# Is "arbitrarily awarded hotness points" meant as a joke?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange.com, hot-questions

When you hover over "Hot Network Questions" on the main page, there's a text saying they have been "arbitrarily" awarded hotness points.

Since English is not my native language, I had to look up the meanings of *arbitrary*, which seem to be:

> 1. *(usually of a decision)* Based on individual discretion or judgment; not based on any objective distinction, perhaps even made at random.
> 2. Determined by impulse rather than reason; heavy-handed.
> 3. *(mathematics)* Any, out of all that are possible. The equation is true for an arbitrary value of x.
> 4. Determined by independent arbiter.

I know from other questions and answers here that "Hot Network Questions" are not manually selected. Rather, they are automatically selected by a computer program following a certain formula. Looking at the [synonyms and antonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/arbitrary) of *arbitrary*, this leads me to ask whether this word is used as a joke, since the opposite seems to be the case?

Or is the idea that the *selection algorithm itself* (being man-made) is written in such a way that some people may find it unreasonable and arbitrary?

Comment: It's meant as a trigger

Comment: @random What do you mean by "trigger"?

Comment: I think the overall message is: don't take it too seriously. Just like we abjure users not to take "imaginary internet points" (aka *rep*) too seriously. SE needed to pick *some* method to advertise sub-sites to people who might not otherwise explore, and the one they selected is the HNQ algo. Like any other decision, it has pros and cons.

Comment: @DanBron Yes, makes sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Or is the idea that the selection algorithm itself (being man-made) is written in such a way that some people may find it unreasonable and arbitrary?

Yes, exactly that. The algorithm, or rather, parts of it, have been selected arbitrarily (say - things like the relative weights of different factors).